# C# LinkedList: Possible null reference error?

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm trying to learn some basics of C# (not new to programming in general) and I'm having trouble making some code for a LinkedList work properly. Specifically, I'm getting a "possible null reference" error when assigned a value from the LinkedList to LinkedListNode variable - is it not possible to do this? I got the code off a website (https://dev.to/adavidoaiei/fundamental-data-structures-and-algorithms-in-c-4ocf) so it seems odd to me that the code would be completely wrong.

This is a section of the code causing issues:

```
    // Create the linked list
    string[] words = 
        { "the", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "dog" };
    LinkedList<string> sentence = new LinkedList<string>(words);
    Display(sentence, "The linked list values:");
    Console.WriteLine("sentence.Contains(\"jumps\") = {0}",
        sentence.Contains("jumps"));

    // Add the word 'today' to the beginning of the linked list
    sentence.AddFirst("today");
    Display(sentence, "Test 1: Add 'today' to beginning of the list:");

    // Move the first node to be the last node
    LinkedListNode<string> mark1 = sentence.First;
    sentence.RemoveFirst();
    sentence.AddLast(mark1);
    Display(sentence, "Test 2: Move first node to be last node:");
```

When initialising the variable 'mark1', I'm getting a "possible null reference error":

```
LinkedListNode<string> mark1 = sentence.First;
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible at all or is this the completely wrong way to work with a LinkedList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the signature for the [`ListedList<T>.First` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.first?view=net-6.0):

```
public System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode<T>? First { get; }
```

See that question mark? That means that the value *can* be null.

The warning you're getting (it's a warning, not an error) is telling you that when you go to read the `First` property, it *could* have a null value, and you *could* be assigning a null value to something that *shouldn't* have a null value assigned to it.

Now, unfortunately the current c# compiler isn't smart enough to recognize that something like this can't have `null` with an example like this:

```
LinkedList<string> sentence = new LinkedList<string>();
sentence.AddFirst("today");
string a = sentence.First.Value;
// last line will have a warning for "sentence.First" possibly being null.
```

Three options to fix this.

1. "I know better". Use the "null forgiveness" operator (`!`) after the thing that the compiler *thinks* could be null to force it to treat it as always not-null.

   ```
   string a = sentence.First!.Value;
   ```
2. "Check it". Do a simple null check beforehand.

   ```
   if (sentence.First is not null)
       string a = sentence.First.Value;
   ```
3. Disable nullable reference types feature. I really don't recommend this.

---

Also, general warning: all of this is *compile time checks*. It has no power for null checking/enforcement when the program is running. A variable marked as "non-nullable" *can* be set to null when the program runs.

Comment: For my own curiousity (I was basically posting the same answer!), wouldn't `?.Value` be safer than `!.Value`

Comment: Use `?.` if you expect `First` _could_ be null. This would prevent `.Value` from throwing a NRE. Use `!.` if you _know_ `First` _shouldn't_ be null, and if it is something terrible has happened. So, it depends on if you want null back or you always expect First to be populated.